# If-statement and logical operators

Tags: java, string, if-statement, logical-operators

I am working on an exercise from an introduction course book. The exercise is to write a program that prompts the user to enter two characters and display the major and status represented in the characters. The first character indicates the major and the second is a number character 1, 2, 3, 4, which indicates whether a student is a freshman, sophomore, junior or senior. Suppose the following characters are used to denote majors:

I: Information Management

C: Computer Science

A: Accounting

The letter character is typed first, and the number character second. So far the program works as long as both characters are typed right. If the characters are typed wrong, i.e T3, the program should print "Invalid input". The program prints "Invalid input" if the letter character is typed right, and number character wrong. But if the letter character is typed wrong, and the number character right, the program prints a blank space instead of the major, plus title. In the last if-statement I have tried to make a condition which says that if any other character than either 'I', 'C', or 'A' is typed in along with a number character that is not in the interval between 1 and 4, the program should print "Invalid input". Can anyone see what is wrong? Code example below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MajorAndStatus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String major = "";
        String title = "";

        System.out.println("Enter 2 characters: ");

        String inputString = input.nextLine();

        if (inputString.charAt(0) == 'I') {
            major = "Information Management";
        }
            else if(inputString.charAt(0) == 'C') {
                major = "Computer Science";
            }
            else if(inputString.charAt(0) == 'A') {
                major  = "Accounting";
            }


        if (inputString.charAt(1) == '1') {
            title = "Freshman";
        }
            else if(inputString.charAt(1) == '2') {
                title = "Sophomore";
            }
            else if(inputString.charAt(1) == '3') {
                title  = "Junior";
            }
            else if(inputString.charAt(1) == '4') {
                title  = "Senior";
            }

        if (((inputString.charAt(0) != 'I' || inputString.charAt(0) != 'C' || inputString.charAt(0) != 'A')) & ((inputString.charAt(1) < '1' || inputString.charAt(1) > '4'))) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(major + " " + title);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to tend to read the conditions wrong. Try reading them out loud may help to understand your problem better (at least that's what i'm teaching my students). You write "IF my first character is not an 'I' or not a 'C' or not a 'A'..." but you actually mean "IF my first character is neither of 'I' and 'C' and 'A' ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition for printing `Invalid Input` is wrong.

It should be

```
if (((inputString.charAt(0) != 'I' && inputString.charAt(0) != 'C' && inputString.charAt(0) != 'A')) || ((inputString.charAt(1) < '1' || inputString.charAt(1) > '4')))
```

However, I'd eliminate that if statement.

Instead, add an `else` cluase to your to if-else-if statements :

```
    if (inputString.charAt(0) == 'I') {
        major = "Information Management";
    } else if(inputString.charAt(0) == 'C') {
        major = "Computer Science";
    } else if(inputString.charAt(0) == 'A') {
        major  = "Accounting";
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }

    if (inputString.charAt(1) == '1') {
        title = "Freshman";
    } else if(inputString.charAt(1) == '2') {
        title = "Sophomore";
    } else if(inputString.charAt(1) == '3') {
        title  = "Junior";
    } else if(inputString.charAt(1) == '4') {
        title  = "Senior";
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }

    if (!major.equals("") && !title.equals("")) {
        System.out.println(major + " " + title);
    }
```

EDIT :

I you wish "Invalid Input" to be printed only once, you can check the value of the `major` and `title` variables to determine if the correct input was entered:

```
    if (inputString.charAt(0) == 'I') {
        major = "Information Management";
    } else if(inputString.charAt(0) == 'C') {
        major = "Computer Science";
    } else if(inputString.charAt(0) == 'A') {
        major  = "Accounting";
    }

    if (inputString.charAt(1) == '1') {
        title = "Freshman";
    } else if(inputString.charAt(1) == '2') {
        title = "Sophomore";
    } else if(inputString.charAt(1) == '3') {
        title  = "Junior";
    } else if(inputString.charAt(1) == '4') {
        title  = "Senior";
    }

    if (!major.equals("") && !title.equals("")) {
        System.out.println(major + " " + title);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! The code didn't quite work out as it should. If any characters are invalid, "Invalid input" should be printed once. When i tested your code and typed i.e A6, I get the output "Accouning" on the first line, and "Invalid input on the second. Not that it's a really big deal, but I just wated to get it to work like the author of the book intented.

Comment: @Esben86 I didn't notice you were initializing the variables to `""`. I was assuming they were initialized to `null`. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for errors at the bottom of your program, why don't you add in an `else` to your `if` statements, which will print `invalid input`.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
if (inputString.charAt(0) == 'I') {
    major = "Information Management";
}
else if(inputString.charAt(0) == 'C') {
    major = "Computer Science";
}
else if(inputString.charAt(0) == 'A') {
    major  = "Accounting";
}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
}
```

You can add in the same `else` to your `if` statement for the second character too.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Your suggestion is similiar to the one above, where i replied the following: 
 
 
The code didn't quite work out as it should. If any characters are invalid, "Invalid input" should be printed once. When i tested your code and typed i.e A6, I get the output "Accouning" on the first line, and "Invalid input on the second. Not that it's a really big deal, but I just wated to get it to work like the author of the book intented.

Answer (score 0):

Both aswers don't detect problems with too short string (IndexOutOfBoundsException)

replace

```
   String inputString = input.nextLine();

    if (inputString.charAt(0) == 'I') {
    ... }
```

with

```
    String inputString = input.nextLine();
    if(inputString.length<2) {
         System.out.println("Type a least 2 charactyes");
    }
    if (inputString.charAt(0) == 'I') {
    ... }
```